# Can not connect to Kafka with port 9092

Tags: python-2.7, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafka-python

I created a topic with replica=2 in kafka, and kafka is running in my docker machine. 
[image]

Usually, I should be able to connect to docker with port 9092. but I can't

[image]

While, I am able to connect using 32783. Not sure what's the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's the Docker run command (which is not shown in the question). 9092 internally is being mapped out to 32783,32784,32785. I am guessing the three docker run commands were `-p 32783:9092` etc.

You should run it with `-p 9092:9092` if you want it to be 9092 on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac, I run Kafka in a container like this (note `ADVERTISED_HOST` env var):

`` docker run --name st-kafka -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --add-host=dockerhost:`docker-machine ip dev-st` -e ADVERTISED_HOST=`docker-machine ip dev-st` -e ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 -d spotify/kafka ``

I like `spotify/kafka` because it contains both ZK and Kafka in the same container (nice for local dev environment). The latest version is `0.8.2` I think, so you should use a different image or make your own `Dockerfile` with version 0.9, if that's the one you need.